# How to publish jar to nexus through curl?

Tags: nexus

curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file abclog.jar http://111.111.1.121:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/keshri/fileupload/

Comment: You need to include the jar name at the end of the URL

Comment: @rseddon the one which i mentioned is working

Comment: To delete the jar we can use.                                                                       
curl -v --request DELETE  --user "admin:admin123"  --silent  http://111.111.1.126:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/keshri/fileUpload/abc.jar

Answer (score 0):

This works on nexus 3.12 (from windows, uploading a nuget package)

```
$curl.exe" -u ${NUGET_DEPLOYER_USER}:${NUGET_DEPLOYER_PASS} -F filename=the_artifact.nupkg 
http://mynexus.example.org:9881/nexus/service/extdirect -F file=c:\\fakepath\\the_artifact.nupkg 
-F repositoryName=nuget-hosted -F extTID=36 -F extAction=coreui_Upload 
-F extMethod=doUpload -F extType=rpc -F extUpload=true
```

On 3.14 it fails with something about an csrf token being missing.